# compile c++ with clang - newbie

Tags: c++

I found this code in a tutorial

http://www.penguinprogrammer.co.uk/c-beginners-tutorial/introduction/

```
// This line is necessary to be able to output information to the screen
#include <iostream>

// The program starts here and carries on line by line
int main(){
    // Create two integers a and b containing 10 and 5
    int a = 10;
    int b = 5;

    /* Add them together and store the result in another
       integer called sum */
    int sum = a + b;

    // Output the sum to the screen
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    // End the program and send a value of 0 (success) back
    // to the operating system
    return 0;
}
```

I want to compile it

Have installed `clang` by doing

```
apt-get install clang
```

Compiling by doing

```
clang -x c++ tutorial.cpp
```

## error

```
/tmp/tutorial-aa5f7a.o: In function `main':
tutorial.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'
tutorial.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
tutorial.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
tutorial.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/tutorial-aa5f7a.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init':
tutorial.cpp:(.text.startup+0x13): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
tutorial.cpp:(.text.startup+0x19): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clang++ tutorial.cpp` - the `-x c++` is useful if you only want to compile the source file, using `-c`, but if you are also linking the application into an executable, you want `clang` to know that you are linking a C++ application, and add the c++ libraries to the link command (if you want to see what `clang` actually does, add the `-v` option.